Offline open circuit detector for PM DC motor
How can I create a circuit to detect if a motor is connected or not without running the motor?
I'm designing a power wheelchair and need to implement an offline open circuit detector for a Permanent Magnet (PM) DC motor. Despite studying a detailed PDF guide on motor diagnostics, I'm still unclear on how to design this circuit
Many power wheelchairs can detect an open circuit without passing any voltage. For instance, in one wheelchair, when I checked the voltage on the motor, it was 0V. However, as soon as I disconnected the motor, an error was triggered. This suggests the system detects the motor connection without applying voltage.
Additionally, the board I inspected only had a MOSFET and some basic components, which complicates my understanding of how the detection works.
My questions are:

Concept: How can an open circuit detector identify a motor connection in an offline state
Components: Given that only a MOSFET and basic components were used, what is the likely method of detection?
Design: Are there example schematics for such detectors?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Measure the voltage at the pins where the motor was connected after you disconnect it. You might read some there, and if so I'd suspect some low quiescent current. Please [edit] your question to add your findings.

yes, that's how I measured the voltage, both before and after disconnecting the motor

If you measure with a multimeter and observe no voltage at all, actually zero, it could be a very short pulsed one. Consider to measure with an oscilloscope. Without current there is no detection, and if you remove the load, even a low current will produce voltage.
